# I want to configure a remote desktop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to configure a remote desktop(windows server) on AWS which will be used by around 15 users, Can anyone tell me how much memory & CPU and much it will cost.

Comment: I don't think you can have 15 people RDP into the same computer. Or do they each want their own virtual computer?

Comment: Go for amazon workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Hearing your 15 users' requirement, I think it's better to go with Amazon Workspaces.

I think it would be a budget solution when considering both cost and human effort, especially for a small team.

Amazon WorkSpaces provides the flexibility to pay monthly or hourly. The charges for the Service apply on a monthly basis. With monthly billing, you pay a fixed monthly fee for unlimited usage during the month, which is best for workers who use their Amazon WorkSpace full-time or as their primary desktop.

With hourly billing, you pay a small fixed monthly fee per WorkSpace to cover infrastructure costs and storage, and a low hourly rate for each hour the WorkSpace is used during the month. Hourly billing works best when Amazon WorkSpaces are used, on average, for less than a full working day or for just a few days a month, making it ideal for part-time workers,  short-term projects, and education.